# sound classfication using mfcc and dynamic time warping (dtw)

Tags: mfcc

My objective is to classify non-speech signal for which I am using mfcc and dtw in java. However I am stuck in middle. I would appreciate any help.
I have evaluated 13 mfcc values for each frame however some values are negative, I am confused whether the process I am following is right or wrong. Currently I am using the code provided by JAudio. I have also tried other code, they give me negative values as well.

Secondly, I get 13 coefficients for each frame, considering 157 frames for a certain length of sample, I get 157 sets of 13 mfccs. I am having hard time how to use all the coefficients in DTW because dtw only gives closest distance between two time signals. I do have code of DTW to compare two time signals. I am not sure how to use all the mfccs values of the signal as features.

Is there some crucial step of classification I am missing? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have N1 sets of 13 MFCCs each for the first signal and N2 sets of MFCCs for the second.
You should compute the distance between each *set* in from the first signal and each *set* from the second (you can use the [Euclidian Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) for the distance between two 13-sized arrays)

This would leave you with an N1xN2 bidimensional array on which you should now apply the DTW.

Comment: Can you explain what are _13-sized arrays_ and _N1xN2 bidimensional array_? Also it is confusing what you mean by _set_. Currently, it looks like you suggest applying DTW on N1xN2 matrix. If that's the case, it doesn't make sense to me at all. You will end up with a vector corresponding to optimal warping against two matrices whereas DTW is to be computed against two vectors representing a similar signal. And those vectors make a matrix, as far as DTW is concerned. More than that, I still don't understand where are those 13 coefficients in all this.

Answer (score 1):

The use of DTW suppose to verify 2 audio sequences in your case. Thus, for the sequence to be verify you will have a matrix M1xN and for the query M2xN. This implies that your cost matrix will have M1xM2.

To construct the cost matrix you have to apply a distance/cost measure between the sequences, as cost(i,j) = your_chosen_multidimension_metric(M1[i,:],M2[j,:])

The resulted cost matrix will be 2D, and you could apply easily DTW.

I made a similar code for DTW based on MFCC. Below is the Python implementation which returs DTW score; x and y are the MFCC matrix of voice sequences, with M1xN and M2xN dimensions:

```
def my_dtw (x, y):
    cost_matrix = cdist(x, y,metric='seuclidean')
    m,n = np.shape(cost_matrix)
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            if ((i==0) & (j==0)):
                cost_matrix[i,j] = cost_matrix[i,j]

            elif (i==0):
                cost_matrix[i,j] = cost_matrix[i,j] + cost_matrix[i,j-1]

            elif (j==0):
                cost_matrix[i,j] = cost_matrix[i,j] + cost_matrix[i-1,j]

            else:
                min_local_dist = cost_matrix[i-1,j]

                if min_local_dist > cost_matrix[i,j-1]:
                    min_local_dist = cost_matrix[i,j-1]

                if min_local_dist > cost_matrix[i-1,j-1]:
                    min_local_dist = cost_matrix[i-1,j-1]

                cost_matrix[i,j] = cost_matrix[i,j] + min_local_dist
    return cost_matrix[m-1,n-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out: http://code.google.com/p/aquila/
Specifically: http://code.google.com/p/aquila/source/browse/trunk/examples/dtw_distance/main.cpp which has an example codeof dtw distace calculation.